# Updating a controller scope through a service

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, promise

My pages load by calling the listObjects function in the AWS S3 bucket.  This is basically an asynchronous call which gets a bunch of objects in AWS S3.

This works fine if I put this call in the controller and then do a $scope.$apply() when the asynchronous call returns and all the data is processed.

However, every page basically has to make this same call to the S3 bucket to populate the page so I basically have the same code pasted onto every controller.

The obvious thing to do would be to move this code into a service but how do I update the scope in the controller through a service?  I can't do $scope.$apply() in my service.

How do I let my controller that called the service know that the asynchronous call has finished processesing and update the $scope variable in the controller?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to make use of `Promises` and the Angular `$q` Service. For this, simply create a Service Function which returns a Promise. You can then wait for this Promise in your Controller and if it gets resolved, you can assign the response to the `$scope` of the Controller.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YyNSY3fL0asUPcCMX1oc) (check dev Tools)

I have created a simple demo:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function(demoService) {

  var self = this;

  self.init = init;
  self.list = {};

  init();

  function init () {

    console.log("call async Service Method");
    demoService.getListObjects()
      .then(function (list) {
        console.log("received", list);
        // Assign Response to the Scope
        self.list = list;
      });
  }
});


app.service('demoService', function($q) {
  var self = this;

  self.getListObjects = getListObjects;

  function getListObjects() {
    var deferred= $q.defer();

    // Simulate Async Action
    setTimeout(function () {
      var list = {};
      deferred.resolve(list);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with this and check back later.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array of objects from Service method and assign it in the controller call method.

Service:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .service('servS3', servS3);

function servS3()
{
   var service = {
      gets3List = gets3List
   };
   return service;

  function gets3List(){
       //Write your logic and return array of s3 List

  };
}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.s3ListObject = [];

servS3.gets3List()
.then(function(response){
  $scope.s3ListObject = response.data;
});
```

Also, if caching can be done then, try to cache this S3Data (on a sessionStorage) during the login, rather than loading the data everytime which may impact performance.

Comment: I shouldn't have to worry about caching if I'm using routes correct?  I thought angular caches your route states by default.

Comment: I am talking about the data caching. If the list objects from AWS S3 Bucket is not going to differ page to page then call the method only once and store it in session storage. This will avoid multiple round trips to the list objects function of the AWS s3 bucket.